# Encountering _jspService is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit issue in JBOSS EAP7

Tags: java, jsp, jboss, jboss-eap-7

I was encountering JBWEB004061: An error occurred at line: 129 in the generated java file
The code of method _jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit.

I have tried several solution around the web and issue still persists.

I am using JBOSS EAP 7 as the server.
Included apache tomcat in the runtime of the project

Note: I am migrating servers from Websphere to JBOSS. No problem in Websphere at all.

Any light and output would be appreciated.

Here are the stacktrace of the error:

```
2019-05-30 12:10:12,893 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-25) UT005023: Exception handling request to /%Path%/template.jsp: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: JBWEB004062: Unable to compile class for JSP:

JBWEB004061: An error occurred at line: 129 in the generated java file
The code of method _jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit

Stacktrace:
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:95)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:198)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:449)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:359)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
        at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:652)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:358)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:402)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:346)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.jsp.JspFileHandler.handleRequest(JspFileHandler.java:32)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:266)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchToServlet(ServletInitialHandler.java:211)
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.includeImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:352)
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.include(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:265)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:907)
        at org.apache.jsp.jsp.common.template_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fwhen_005f4(template_jsp.java:882)
        at org.apache.jsp.jsp.common.template_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fchoose_005f3(template_jsp.java:838)
        at org.apache.jsp.jsp.common.template_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fotherwise_005f2(template_jsp.java:806)
        at org.apache.jsp.jsp.common.template_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fchoose_005f2(template_jsp.java:741)
        at org.apache.jsp.jsp.common.template_jsp._jspService(template_jsp.java:198)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:402)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:346)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.jsp.JspFileHandler.handleRequest(JspFileHandler.java:32)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:266)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchToPath(ServletInitialHandler.java:201)
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:202)
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:109)
        at ph.com.common.servlet.CommonServlet.performTask(CommonServlet.java:364)
        at ph.com.common.servlet.CommonServlet.doPost(CommonServlet.java:78)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:285)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:264)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:175)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:792)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: For JBoss EAP 7 on server level configuration, you can update `standalone.xml`, inside undertow subsystem replace jsp-config with

`<jsp-config development="true" mapped-file="false"/>`

Comment: @Abhijeet I have this in my standalone.xml      <servlet-container name="default">
               <jsp-config development="true" trim-spaces="true" tag-pooling="false" mapped-file="false" generate-strings-as-char-arrays="true"/> 
                <websockets/>
            </servlet-container>  killed and restarted the jboss service, still no luck

Comment: @Swati i already tested some of the solution in there. All of my jsp includes are dynamic includes in my template.jsp.  I also tried the web.xml config (mappedfile = false) but it downloads the webpage when accessing it.

Comment: Then the only way to solve the issue is by splitting your code and using `jsp:include`

Comment: @Abhijeet  I only have 348 line of code and some of them are comments. I used jsp:include page

Comment: Can you post your jsp code here

Comment: already posted below. Thanks @Abhijeet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already solved it by adding:

```
   <jsp-config generate-strings-as-char-arrays="true" mapped-file="false" tag-pooling="false" trim-spaces="true"/>
```

in %JBoss_path%/domain/configuration/domain.xml

my fault is I just added the same code in the standalone.xml

Thanks all!